# NSURLConnection delegates not being called even when run on main thread

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, nsurlconnection

I know that this kind of question has been asked many times, but all of them point to saying that the connection must be on a different thread.

```
-(void)distanceMatrix{

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:distanceMatrixURL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];

connection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[connection2 scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                      forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

NSLog(@"Is%@ main thread", ([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"" : @" NOT"));
[connection2 start];

if (connection2)
{
    responseData2 = [NSMutableData data];
    connectionIsActive = YES;    
} else {
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
}

- (void)connection2:(NSURLConnection *)connection2 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{NSLog(@"recieved response");
[responseData2 setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection2:(NSURLConnection *)connection2 didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[responseData2 appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection2:(NSURLConnection *)connection2 didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
connectionIsActive = NO;
    NSLog(@"failed!!");
}

- (void)connection2DidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{  

connectionIsActive          = NO;
SBJsonParser *json          = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSString *responseString    = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError          = nil;

NSDictionary *parsedJSON    = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&jsonError];

travelTime= [[[[parsedJSON valueForKey:@"rows"] valueForKey:@"elements"] valueForKey:@"duration"] valueForKey:@"text"];

NSLog(@"traveltime = %@", travelTime);
}
```

When I log it, it says that it runs on the main thread. Connection2 is active but none of the delegates are called.

Also, this is the way I am calling distanceMatrix method

```
-(id)initWithJsonResultDict:(NSDictionary *)jsonResultDict andUserCoordinates:    (CLLocationCoordinate2D)userCoords andTimeURL:(NSString*)timeURL
{
self.distanceMatrixURL = timeURL;
[self distanceMatrix];
//more code here for other purposes
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have added a `2` into the names of all of the delegate methods. That changes the method signature so you aren't implementing the correct methods. Remove all of the `2` at the start of the methods `- (void)connection2:` and it should work.

Comment: Yup ;) +1 @Spenciefy you need to prove which connection you are using inside each delegate method.

Comment: thanks. not so sure what I was thinking with the 2. seems to work now.